# How to delete the index before the cursor in a input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, input, slice

I have a input field and I want to delete the index/character which is before the cursor.

i have tried following:

```
document.getElementById('input').value = document.getElementById('input').value.slice(document.getElementById('input').selectionStart, 1);
```

i've tried some other values for the second argument in the slice method but i think i dont really understand it.

Comment: Look up the definition of slice.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand why you need this, but if you want to omit the character coming just before the caret and then get the whole string without it you can do it like this:

```
input.value = input.value.slice(0, input.selectionStart - 1) + input.value.slice(input.selectionStart, input.value.length);
```